# Create an rpt file without crystal report designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report, business-objects-sdk

Is it possible to create a crytal report file without using the designer in visual studio? I mean create it programmatically in C# code.  I didn't find any helpful tutorial to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Report Application Server ([RAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225325%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) API to create or modify crystal reports.

Edit:

[Tutorials](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/index?rid=/webcontent/uuid/b02c1cac-ad86-2b10-88ae-cb36551bab06).

Comment: Do you have any sample of the use of RAS within c#?

Comment: Hi! I have a question: how could I use stored procedure with the RAS sdk. I have a stored procedure with multiple parameters and I want to use it as a data source for my dynamic report.